# How to hide the back-end URL in browser developer tools?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How to hide the backend URL in browser developer tools for my front end application which is on Angular, HTML 5?
When ever a backend call is made from my UI, the URL being used is shown in developer tool of a browser. How can I hide/mask this URL so that the user is not able to see/get the URL of the back end?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The only thing you can do is secure your backend service.

Comment: @Vishwanath: ...which you have to do anyway, since network sniffers are a thing. Non-browser requests are a thing. Domain scanning is a thing.

Comment: "Protect" isn't quite a good word, I should say "you must **secure** your backend" sounds better, as @T.J.Crowder said, there is plenty of "things" out there. There are lots of strategies that you could elaborate as authentication, authorization and encryption for example.

Comment: I would add, although this applies more to web applications than others, it's not a problem with web applications specifically, but a problem with client applications in general. You should always assume that a client running an application can gain full knowledge of its inner workings and modify it if they want (because they always can, given enough time and effort), and design your systems' security based on this.